# Dijkstra by means of Heap and pred-field

Tags: heap, graph-algorithm, dijkstra

I have the following task, but I have no idea how to do it?

*Calculate (lexicographically) the shortest path from V1-node to the other nodes by means of Dijkstra. Please write the current Heaps and corresponding Pred-fields as well. Start with new Heap and pred-field before the ExtractMin-Call.*

[image]

I got this result via Dijkstra, but how should I add it to the min-heap (tree)?

[image]

Comment: Dijkstra is an algorithm for calculating the shortest path, if you know how to implement that algorithm then you can solve this problem. It's hard to say what exactly ExtractMin-Call is and Pre-fields without more context? Anyways you can just follow along the steps in the wiki page to find the shortest path: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm .

Comment: I have been trying to solve the task for a few days without success

Comment: This seems like a homework problem. Dijkstra is a pretty common algorithm for which you can easily find implementations online.

Comment: @Anmol Singh Jaggi, I have added to my question the solution via dijkstra, but how should I fill min-heap? how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

I found exactly this task in an old exam I use for learning algorithms. I wasn't sure how to solve it so I searched several books for any explanation on how the minheap works along with Dijkstra and didn't find any. Finally I figured it out. So I hope this helps to understand how to solve this problem.

- Step 1: Draw the heap lexicographically: V1 -> root, and then the
  other nodes from left to right. V1 has the value 0, all other nodes
  inf.
- Step 2: ExtractMin(): swap root (which has the lowest value)
  with the very last node and cut it off.
- Step 3: Relaxation: Update new values for the nodes, if value decreases. "What is the new value from start to X when
  I walk via the node, I just extracted, respecting its predecessors? Is it less than the old value, then update."
- Step 4: Update the predecessor field if there is a better path.
- Step 5: Call Heapify(): Resort the heap, so that
  the node with the lowest value becomes root.
- Repeat Step 2 to 5 until there are no nodes left.